# Android Tic tac toe Gaming Winning Condition

Tags: android, tic-tac-toe

Hello I'm new to Android Programming i need some help in Tic tac toe Game 
I make very simple Application that work only with Button here is The Code please have a look

XML

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn4"
    android:background="#09851a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#09851a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:background="#09851a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn4"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#09851a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn7"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn3"
    android:background="#09851a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn3"
    android:background="#09851a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn7"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#09851a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn8"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn5"
    android:background="#09851a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn9"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonMainActivitybtn6"
    android:background="#09851a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Tic Tac Toe Game Day 3"
    android:id="@+id/textViewMainActivityTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Right now i m just applying One Condition i know it is very Dump Programing 
But i just want to work with button can any one guide me with this :) thankyou

```
package com.example.awais_pc.tictactoe;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9;
    Boolean p1=true, p2=true;
    String player1= "X";
    String player2 = "O";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainActivitybtn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainActivitybtn2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainActivitybtn3);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainActivitybtn4);
        btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainActivitybtn5);
        btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainActivitybtn6);
        btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainActivitybtn7);
        btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainActivitybtn8);
        btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainActivitybtn9);

        final String b1 = (String) btn1.getText();
        final String b2 = (String) btn2.getText();
        final String b3 = (String) btn3.getText();
        final String b4 = (String) btn4.getText();
        final String b5 = (String) btn5.getText();
        final String b6 = (String) btn6.getText();
        final String b7 = (String) btn7.getText();
        final String b8 = (String) btn8.getText();
        final String b9 = (String) btn9.getText();

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(b1.trim().isEmpty()){
                   if(p1 == true){
                       btn1.setText(player1);
                       p1 = false;
                       p2 = true;
                       btn1.setEnabled(false);

                   }
                   else if(p2 == true){
                       btn1.setText(player2);
                       p1 = true;
                       p2 = false;
                       btn1.setEnabled(false);
                   }

                }
            }
        }); // End Button One

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(b2.trim().isEmpty()){
                    if(p1 == true){
                        btn2.setText(player1);
                        p1 = false;
                        p2 = true;
                        btn2.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else if(p2 == true){
                        btn2.setText(player2);
                        p1 = true;
                        p2 = false;
                        btn2.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }); // end button two
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(b3.trim().isEmpty()){
                    if(p1 == true){
                        btn3.setText(player1);
                        p1 = false;
                        p2 = true;
                        btn3.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else if(p2 == true){
                        btn3.setText(player2);
                        p1 = true;
                        p2 = false;
                        btn3.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }); // end button Three
        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(b4.trim().isEmpty()){
                    if(p1 == true){
                        btn4.setText(player1);
                        p1 = false;
                        p2 = true;
                        btn4.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else if(p2 == true){
                        btn4.setText(player2);
                        p1 = true;
                        p2 = false;
                        btn4.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }); // end button Four
        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String b5 = btn5.getText().toString();
                if(b5.trim().isEmpty()){
                    if(p1 == true){
                        btn5.setText(player1);
                        p1 = false;
                        p2 = true;
                        btn5.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else if(p2 == true){
                        btn5.setText(player2);
                        p1 = true;
                        p2 = false;
                        btn5.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }); // end button Five
        btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(b6.trim().isEmpty()){
                    if(p1 == true){
                        btn6.setText(player1);
                        p1 = false;
                        p2 = true;
                        btn6.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else if(p2 == true){
                        btn6.setText(player2);
                        p1 = true;
                        p2 = false;
                        btn6.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }); // end button Six
        btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(b7.trim().isEmpty()){
                    if(p1 == true){
                        btn7.setText(player1);
                        p1 = false;
                        p2 = true;
                        btn7.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else if(p2 == true){
                        btn7.setText(player2);
                        p1 = true;
                        p2 = false;
                        btn7.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }); // end button Seven
        btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(b8.trim().isEmpty()){
                    if(p1 == true){
                        btn8.setText(player1);
                        p1 = false;
                        p2 = true;
                        btn8.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else if(p2 == true){
                        btn8.setText(player2);
                        p1 = true;
                        p2 = false;
                        btn8.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }); // end button Eight

        btn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(b9.trim().isEmpty()){
                    if(p1 == true){
                        btn9.setText(player1);
                        p1 = false;
                        p2 = true;
                        btn9.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else if(p2 == true){
                        btn9.setText(player2);
                        p1 = true;
                        p2 = false;
                        btn9.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }); // end button Nine
// WInning Condition But it is not working please look

        if(b1.equalsIgnoreCase("X")&&
                b2.equalsIgnoreCase("X")&&
                b3.equalsIgnoreCase("X")){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Player One Win The Game",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }

    }//end on create


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared your `Strings` as `final` and you set them in the `onCreate()` but they have no text specified until you click them. So you aren't comparing anything. Instead assign the corresponding text in your `onClickListener()` after you set the `button` text.

```
btn1.setText(player1);
b1 = btn1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: So what should i do ?
i didnt declare as final but android stutio said to me to declare like this :|

Comment: You see how you declared your `player` variables outside of the `onCreate()` scope? Do the same for your Strings, then you won't have to declare them as final as they'll be global variables. Then do what I posted.